# Hamming distance in Scala

Tags: programming-challenge, unit-testing, scala, edit-distance

**Problem**

> Write a program that can calculate the Hamming difference between two DNA strands.
>
> ```
> GAGCCTACTAACGGGAT
> CATCGTAATGACGGCCT
> ^ ^ ^  ^ ^    ^^
> ```

**Code**

```
object Hamming {
  def compute(s1: String, s2: String): Int = {
    if (s1.length != s2.length)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException()
    (s1.toList).zip(s2.toList)
               .filter(current => current._1 != current._2)
               .length
  }  
}
```

**Test Suite**

```
import org.scalatest._

class HammingSpecs extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  it should "detect no difference between empty strands" in {
    Hamming.compute("", "") should be (0)
  }

  it should "detect no difference between identical strands" in {
    Hamming.compute("GGACTGA", "GGACTGA") should be (0)
  }

  it should "detect complete hamming distance in small strand" in {
    Hamming.compute("ACT", "GGA") should be (3)
  }

  it should "give hamming distance in off by one strand" in {
    Hamming.compute("GGACGGATTCTG", "AGGACGGATTCT") should be (9)
  }

  it should "give small hamming distance in middle somewhere" in {
    Hamming.compute("GGACG", "GGTCG") should be (1)
  }

  it should "give a larger distance" in {
    Hamming.compute("ACCAGGG", "ACTATGG") should be (2)
  }

  it should "be undefined for strands of unequal length" in {
    an[IllegalArgumentException] should be thrownBy {
      Hamming.compute("AAACTAGGGG", "AGGCTAGCGGTAGGAC")
    }
  }
}
```

[Source](http://exercism.io/exercises/scala/hamming/readme)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strings have a `.zip()` method; calling `.toList()` is superfluous.

Instead of `.filter(…)` and `.length()`, use [`.count(…)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.collection.Traversable@count(p:A=>Boolean):Int).

I'm not a fan of the name `current`, which has a connotation of iteration.

Avoid omitting braces with `if` statements.  If you want to do so, put the body on the same line to avoid accidents.

```
object Hamming {
  def compute(s1: String, s2: String): Int = {
    if (s1.length != s2.length) throw new IllegalArgumentException()
    s1.zip(s2).count(pair => pair._1 != pair._2)
  }  
}
```

Comment: Is there a class diagram or something like that to take the reference of the methods on types?

Comment: I just go by the official API documentation that I cited. I don't know if there is a better reference.